# Check each string value in dictionary for specific characters c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read through a dictionary and get all the values in it  then check if the value in the dictionary location is equal to (A) when a button is clicked 
if the value in the dictionary ends with (A) then the word "correct" is printed , else "incorrect is printed"

but that happens when i click the button is that the correctness and in-correctness of each value is printed. so it does identify the correct answer and the incorrect answer but i only need it to print out either  correct  of incorrect

the issue occurs in the OnGUI function.

the code allows for a random key which are questions  to be selected on button click and its values which are answers displayed as buttons , you then click a button . correct answers are the values that end with (A) . bu clicking the buttons which are displayed with the value name you will check if you have selected the correct answer but there is a slight problem with it . it prints out the correctness and in-correctness of each value in the selected key

here is the entire code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class testQuestions : MonoBehaviour {

  Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    string []vl ;
    string ky;
    int Qnum;
    string A;
    int indx;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        dictionary.Add("ups", new string[] {"updegree", "popup (A)"});
        dictionary.Add("down aroud the place like this ", new string[] {"sun", "bun(A)","art"});
        dictionary.Add("left", new string[] {"higi (A)", "migi"});
        dictionary.Add("right", new string[] {"een", "yyo(A)"});
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {



        if (Input.GetKeyDown("q"))
        {
            GenerateRandoms();
        }


    }

    void GenerateRandoms()
    {


        string[] keys = new string[dictionary.Count];//get the dictionary count and store in array
dictionary.Keys.CopyTo(keys, 0);

var index = Random.Range(0, keys.Length);
var key = keys[index];
var value = dictionary[key];
        ky= key;
        vl = value;

foreach (string ku in value)
{

            // create buttons with the ku text as the button text 


            indx = index;
            Qnum +=1;   

            A = ku;


        }
        //---------- remove each after answer button click
        //dictionary.Remove(key); // remove key after it is already displayed. this must only be exicuted at the end of the function

    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        int charlength = 0;
        foreach(char NumOfChar in ky)
        {
            charlength ++;
        }
        GUI.TextArea(new Rect (0,0,charlength*10 + 100,20),"Key is " + ky /*+ " value is " + string.Join(",", vl) + " position is " +int.Parse(indx.ToString())*/);

        for (int i = 0; i < dictionary[dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(indx)].Length; i++)
        {

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect(0, 30 + Screen.height-Screen.height + 40* i, 100, 20),dictionary[dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(indx)][i]))
        {


                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < dictionary[dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(indx)].Length; i2++)
                {
                    string Answer = dictionary[dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(indx)][i2];

            if (Answer.EndsWith("(A)"))
            {
                print ("Correct");
            } 
            else
            {
                print ("Incorrect");        
            }
                }



        }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Any problems with that?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what is supposed to happen without a stated contract of input/output. Generally one access a Value in a dictionary by Key, although *where* the Key comes from here is missing .. this is especially required because **the order of IDictionary.Keys is not guaranteed**. So, backing up: What do the Values "up", "down", etc have to do with checking an answer? Where does `indx` come from and how does it relate to the Values?

Comment: i added the complete code now

Comment: @AltCoder Pay attention to: "the order of IDictionary.Keys is not guaranteed". If this is a *sequence* of questions, consider an IEnumerable/List/etc instead (as these *can* be accessed by index reliably). I would also define a `Question` class that contains the `string Prompt`, `List<string> Choices`, and `string Answer` to help manage everything - then it can be a sequence of these tiny bundles of Question-goodness! (e.g. `IList<Question> questions = LoadQuestions()`)

Comment: my eyes are on fire >.< i dont have time to try new methods 
the issue i have is inside 

`for (int i2 = 0; i2 < dictionary[dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(indx)].Length; i2++)
                {`
everything was fine up until that point .

no worries. i dont need much more functions in this code so i will use this method .

Comment: Okay. Use it. It won't work reliably. The minimum fix required (to at least get the answer checking working although the display order will still be unreliable) is to use `string questionKey` instead of `int indx` or some such. Then one can use `var answersForQuestion = dictionary[questionKey]` and proceed to do useful things. Good luck!

Comment: (However, I strongly advise `IList<Question>` or even `IList<KeyValuePair<..>>` or [`ILookup<..>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291.aspx), etc. There is also [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx), but YMMV and I've given more than my two cents.)

Comment: thanks for your help , I got it working . it was a much easier fix than i thought .
`if (dictionary[dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(indx)][i].EndsWith ("(A)"))`
^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is simply  use an if statement following the initial buttion click event . you check if the source where that button gets its text is the correct answer .

```
if (GUI.Button (new Rect(0, 30 + Screen.height-Screen.height + 40* i, 100, 20),dictionary[dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(indx)][i]))
        {
if (dictionary[dictionary.Keys.ElementAt(indx)][i].EndsWith ("(A)"))
                {
                    print ("Correct");
            } 
            else
            {
                print ("Incorrect");        


                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're loading the available answers to the form, maybe in labels with buttons beside them or the text of the button.  Either way when you load the answers set the tag property of the correct button with an "A".  If the tag of the clicked button has an "A" it's correct.

Changing to something this simple that is easily adapted to the structure you already have, would be much better than trying to make something that is inherently flawed work

In the event handler for the button click something like this should work:

```
    void ButtonClck(object sender, eventargs e)
    {
        Button clickedbutton = (Button)sender;
        if ((string)clickedbutton.Tag = "A")
        {
            print ("Correct");
        } 
        else
        {
            print ("Incorrect");        
        }

    }
```